# What type of succulent plant is this?

Tags: identification, succulents

Can anybody tell me what type of succulent plant this is? The tallest of the plants is approximately 4 feet tall.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Jade plant, botanical name is *Crassula ovata*.